# How to test DbProviderFactories using nunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks, dbproviderfactories

For the below method I want to pass in a mock of the `DbProviderFactories` class but can't because it's a static class:

```
    private DbConnection GetConnection()
     {
        var dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(_name);

            try
            {
                var dbConnection = dbProviderFactory.CreateConnection();
                if (dbConnection == null) return null;
                dbConnection.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
                return dbConnection;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

How can I test my code / how can I mock `DbProviderFactories`?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own non-static wrapper for `DbProviderFactory` that implements your own interface and calls the static method:

```
public interface IDbProviderFactories
{
    DbProviderFactory GetFactory(string name);
}

public class MyDbProviderFactories : IDbProviderFactories
{
    public DbProviderFactory GetFactory(string name)
    {
        return DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(name);
    }
}
```

If you now inject this into your class that exposes `GetConnection()` you can mock an implementation of the interface as needed.

Comment: great help  its looks great .. will get back you soon